# JOIN limited to specific value inf the shared columns

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to narrow down the results returned from a JOIN so that the shared value equal a specific value.

The basic query which returns the entire contents of the tables.

```
SELECT t1.c2, t2.c3 FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.c3 = t2.c4
```

I know I can add t1.c3 to the select list and loop through the returned data to find the t1.c3 with a specific value.  But I am wondering if there is an automagical way to get only the joined data when the value of t1.c3 and t2.c4 = 'xyz'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are simply asking for a condition in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT t1.c2, t2.c3
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.c3 = t2.c4
WHERE t1.c3 = 'xyz';
```

As it is the same column on which you want to filter and join both tables, you can also consider this a cross join on the filtered sets:

```
SELECT q1.c2, q2.c3
FROM       (SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE c3 = 'xyz') q1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE c4 = 'xyz') q2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put your criteria into the join condition:

```
SELECT t1.c2, t2.c3 FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.c3="xyz" and t2.c4="xyz"
```